# Is adding property to only one object of an array in javascript is alright?

Tags: javascript

From time to time I occasionally do JavaScript and i've stumbled upon a question of a "Best practices" matter.
Let's say I have an array of objects of a same type and structure, and I want to mark only one of them with a flag (e.g. isOptimal: true). It's clearly doable, but I was wandering if it's considered as a good/bad practice in JS-world to have only one object containing certain property while other array entries have "undefined" in its place? Maybe there are some downsides, that i'm struggling to see? Undefined-check is present, obviously.
Would really appreciate your opinions on this one, thanks.

Comment: As long as you know what you're doing with it, it's probably fine. Issues arise if other parts of the system cannot depend on it, or if other parts of the system start misbehaving due to the extra property for some reason or another.

Comment: In general no this is not a problem if you know that this can happen and if this is well documented or self explaining in the code. If that part of the code does time consuming calculations, then a uniform structure of all elements in the array could improve performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you pick two objects out of the array, and want to make sure that one is optimal and the other one is not:

```
 if(obj.isOptimal !== obj2.isOptimal)
```

now that will work if `isOptimal` is either `true` or `undefined`, if you set one to `false` the line above stops working as `false !== undefined`.

If you build unstructured data you should always make sure that there are no unwanted side effects, like in this case.

For primitives I would always initialize them to the default value (`""`, `0`, `false`), I would always initialize arrays to an empty one (`[]`), except that `undefined` is a viable option (e.g. if `user.age` is `undefined` we don't know the age yet, if it is `0` the user was just born), you then however have to always check against `undefined` before doing math with that.

For nested objects however, I think that `undefined` is a good default value. You then have to always check if that nested object exist before doing nested accesses:

```
 if(user.car) 
   alert(user.car.model);
```

If you have to add a property to a new structure by adding additional properties (for example the user gets stored in localStorage, then old objects might be in storage that don't have an `isOptimal` property) you could use `Object.assign` to ensure object structure:

```
 const user = Object.assign({ isOptimal: false }, userFromStorage);
```

Comment: That's a one great example. Even though it's not my case, i'm defititely gonna keep it in mind, thanks.

Comment: @yan it is not your case *yet* ... After changing a serverside calculation some of the objects in the database suddenly had NaN values and as more and more math was done with them, the NaN propagated trough the whole system and affected other objects. I finally found out that it was caused by an added property that I did a while ago, and I did not add that to some objects in the database.

Answer (score 3):

It is okay to have different structure to your array of objects. 
This is one of the reasons why NoSQL Document JSON Structures are better at storing non structured data than relational databases where all the objects(as in, tables) should have the same structure.(with null/empty for no value)

But make sure you are not running into troubles by hardcoding the key references when using nested structures and not checking for undefined errors (like `obj.someKey.someValue`, throws error if someKey is not defined in a few objects of the array!)

Comment: *"NoSQL Document JSON Structures are better than relational databases"* – that's a *very* contentious statement. They're better *at some things* and worse at others…

Comment: I have updated the sentence to seem less opinionated. :)

Answer (score 2):

This dynamic possibility is a feature of the JavaScript language. It is possible to do it, but it needs to be managed appropriately. If you start adding too many disparate properties/attributes it can become a mess, and confusing.

An alternative for such a property is to add it to the prototype, to make `isOptimal` a property that defaults to `false`. A falsy check for `undefined` would still work.

Comment: it is not necessary to add a falsy value. the check with `isOptimal` yields the wanted result even if the propery is not set in the object.

Comment: @NinaScholz I just beat you to it by adding an additional sentence.

Answer (score 2):

So you are having array of objects, let's assume it's some kind of data from server. And you have a **findOptimal()** function to find out the optimal one (ones), it runs through all of them and finds the optimal and mark it with **isOptimal** property equal to true.

So you are mutating the original data. And also to filter optimal objects you need to iterate again.

To avoid that you can create an array **optimalObjects** and using **findOptimal()** function push there an index of optimal objects. This way you aren't mutating any data and also finding optimal objects are easier, because you don't need to iterate over them, you have the indexes.